# laravel withCount with count() not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to get jobs count from the jobs table which are having at least one application.
I try with this,

`$jobs_count = Job::withCount('allApplications')->having('all_applications_count', '>', 0)->count();`

but Unknown column 'allApplications_count' error. how to fix that?
but,

`$jobs_count = Job::withCount('allApplications')->having('all_applications_count', '>', 0)->get();`

this is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [has](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence):

```
$jobsWithCommentsCount= Job::has('comments')->count();
```